# If I add a object into an ArrayList at index 1,000,000, will the ArrayList consume a lot of memory?

Tags: java, arraylist

Say the ArrayList is empty before. Then I add one object to the ArrayList at index 1,000,000.

Will the ArrayList create 1,000,001 pointers or just create one pointer?

Comment: If you need to store really sparse data you may want to use a map of some sorts with the "index" as the key, or rethink your algorithm. In any case your question is incredibly easy to try and you should have done so before asking (it probably would have been quicker than asking).

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and at least try it or read about it? -1

Comment: -1 for not simply trying it.

Comment: @Ashish That is incorrect.

Comment: @JasonC thanks jason let me find out more out it.

Answer (score 5):

An IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index > size())

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 2):

Since you ask, you haven't even tried to run it. You will get a IndexOutOfBounds exception.